# Как узнать кто купил мое приложение в play store?

Tags: java, android, google-play

Разместил свое клиентское приложение для сервиса. Предоставлять услугу хочу, только тем, кто купил его в play store. Как идентифицировать пользователя, купившего мое приложение?

Comment: Видел нечто похожее в некоторых приложениях. Допустим если скачал его pro версию оно некоторое время работает без рекламы, а потом выбивает сообщение при заходе "Ошибка инициализации покупки приложения app store, приложение будет работать с рекламой"

Comment: Да, что-то вроде этого и пытаюсь сделать. Сейчас остановился на варианте с реализацией платной подписки через google play services. Там есть возможность проверять состояние покупки через API от Google. Пришлось подключить библиотеку google play services к программе.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и в чём проблема? Вставляете код проверки покупки при включении приложения, там необходимо будет проверять состояние покупки по её ID в **google play console** и дальше в зависимости от конечного результата предоставлять услугу или нет. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) на хорошую библиотеку, которую сам юзаю для покупок. Если жы вы не о внутриигровых покупках, то в случае покупки приложения, когда человек в него зайдёт и так будет понятно, что он его купил, ведь приложение платное, далее вы в этом приложении вставляете аутентификацию к вашему сервису и всё, от сюда вы получите инфу, кто и что купил. Если вы беспокоитесь о том, что возможно кто-то поставил пиратскую версию, то тут намного сложнее, вам необходимо будет сделать отдельный сервис (для себя), который будет отдельно проверять состояние покупки, т.е. не просто доверять функции от Google, которая возвращает True состояние покупке, а после этого ещё проверять пополнился ли счёт от данного пользователя на такую покупку, тут уже готового решения нету, придётся самому делать

Comment: Видимо так, спасибо в любом случае...